# Creating commands and executing them through linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, shell, command-line

I participate in competitive programming contests like codechef. So they take input in a specific format. I am looking to develop a tester in C++. Some things I plan to do are:

- give the format of input in a file format.txt.
- give sample input test cases whose output is know.
- test the program on the test cases(ii) and generate output in separate file.
- test the program randomly on several test cases in accordance with the format specified in format.txt and generate output in separate file.

After having done all this, I want a command to represent all the above operations. How do I introduce a new command( for example `test_codechef sample_program.cpp` where new command executes my tester on sample_program.txt) in the linux terminal?

Comment: Maybe write a bash script?

Comment: I would expect that the hard part is coming up with the input and known output cases. A bash-script or perhaps a bit of python or similar would be the right thing to run the code and compare the output.

Comment: @MatsPetersson basically i'm specifying the format and the ranges wherein the inputs could lie...basically I'm talking about a mini language. As far as the known outputs are concerned, they are generally specified in the question itself as sample inputs and outputs. I suppose I can pipeline them to an output file.

Comment: @Lake bash script is completely alien to me. I am already busy with a lot of other things particularly algorithms for the time being. Could the task be easily done in bash script?

Comment: @sudeepdino008 Well, I guess it would be easy if you knew it, but if you don't you can just write a C++ program that does exactly the same requirements you mention.  All would be easier in a bash script because you can launch programs, use unix commands, etc. easier than having to fork/exec/pipe/dup2 in c.

Comment: @sudeepdino008: Right, the problem is coming up with ANOTHER set of inputs and corresponding outputs, and KNOWING that this is the correct result using your "mini language", that clearly has to be able to cope with quite varied types of requirements - e.g. it may need to produce pairs or triplets of numbers that have some particular non-trivial relationship [e.g. being multiples of two primes - so you need to "know" prime numbers].

Comment: @sudeepdino008 if you want to develop for Linux it is certainly a good idea to learn the scripting language of the shell you want to use (the bash being the default one in most large distributions).

Comment: @Mats Petersson of course I couldn't know that results are correct(other than checking manually). But where the tester will be useful is for checking corner cases, crashes at large inputs,testing the sample input itself, time of execution of program(which matters in competitive programming) etc. As far as your "prime number" point is concerned, it is definitely perfectly valid; But I'm not looking to extend my mini language to include these cases...clearly the effort required is way too much. Knowing the range in which input could lie is more than sufficient in majority of the cases.

Comment: So, I would start by writing something that does that then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a command to Terminal and use it , if you're talking about Bash then just create a file without a type 
example for bash file :

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Hello World "
```

save: HelloWorld

after:

```
chmod +x HelloWorld
cp HelloWorld /usr/bin/
```

then type on Terminal : `HelloWorld` , and the result Hello World , 
so if I'm going correct you need to learn some stuff about Bash Linux

Comment: It's generally considered poor practice to mix binaries you have created yourself in with those supplied by the OS developer in `/usr/bin` - think of OS upgrades/patches. Generally use `/usr/local/bin` or better still `$HOME/bin`.